# how can i get query parameters? for the below given url

Tags: javascript, rest, dojo, dgrid

http://localhost:8080/RestPOC/rest/emp/users?limit(30,780)

how can i get limit parameters in queryparam???

Comment: Split it into 2 arguments:
users?limiStart=30&limitEnd=780

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object to retrieve the parameters.

Take a look at one key `search` which may be your matter of interest.

Check this [SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regExp` to find the values in paranthesis and `split()` to split by comma.

```js
var url = "http://localhost:8080/RestPOC/rest/emp/users?limit(30,780)";

var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
var limits = regExp.exec(url)[1].split(',');

console.log(limits)
```